# How to set A subclass UILabel text ? THREAD ERROR

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to set a UILabel text as follows (All the following code is swift3)

```
 // button Action which select a random text
@IBAction func getResultButton(_ sender: TransitionButton) {

    if( typeTextField.text == "ABC" && pickedCompanyField.text != "XYZ"){
        // query 

        sender.startAnimation()
        // sleep(5)
        sender.stopAnimation(animationStyle: .normal)



    } else if( typeTextField.text == "DEF" && pickedCompanyField.text != "XYZ"){
        // query 

        sender.startAnimation()

        sender.stopAnimation(animationStyle: .shake)
    //    DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.resultLabel.text = "56.36"
    //    }

    }
}
```

and I use the following subclass

```
import UIKit

class CpLabel: UILabel {

    override public var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        get {
            return true
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        sharedInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        sharedInit()
    }

    func sharedInit() {
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: #selector(showMenu(sender:))
        ))
    }

    override func copy(_ sender: Any?) {
        UIPasteboard.general.string = text
        UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(false, animated: true)
    }

    func showMenu(sender: Any?) {
        becomeFirstResponder()
        let menu = UIMenuController.shared
        if !menu.isMenuVisible {
            menu.setTargetRect(bounds, in: self)
            menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
        }
    }

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return (action == #selector(copy(_:)))
    }
}
```

I get this Thread Error ...  I don't know what is causing it ? I have tried to use DispatchQue... function to see if the error regarding main thread stuff but it seems not ? SO Any? Help will be appreciated

Error screenshot: [image]

Comment: While I don't know the issue, what I can see is (1) no code for the `TransitionButton` subclass and (2) two methods/functions in it called `startAnimation` and `stopAnimation` - which is where your screenshot of the error is. Maybe you need to look there? Also, consider trying the "basics" - a simple `UIButton` and a `UIView.animate`.If you can get that to work (which I think you will) then you **know** the issue resides in this `TransitionButton`.

Comment: the button works fine and every other thing is fine if I comment this line:  self.resultLabel.text = "56.36" , if I don't it fire the Thread Error

Comment: What if you keep that line and comment out the animation start/stop?

Comment: Same Error : Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION ..etc

Comment: I don't see the issue then, sorry. I'm assuming that `resultLabel` isn't `nil` when you are trying to set the text....

Comment: From the log it seems that your `resultLabel` is `nil`. If it is an `IBOutlet` make sure that it is connected correctly.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys I found the issue ... It was declared as UILabel and its sub classed to CpLabel , So I changed the deceleration it to CpLabel and it worked..